# In SQL server 2012,when I create any trigger,it shows error "must declare scalar variable"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterDelete12] ON dbo.[project_employee] 
AFTER DELETE
AS

    declare @empname varchar(25);
    declare @emp_password varchar(25);
    declare @emp_username varchar(25);
    declare @audit_action varchar(50);

    select @empname=d.Emp_Name from deleted d;  
    select @emp_password=d.Emp_Password from deleted d; 
    select @emp_username=d.Emp_username from deleted d; 
    set @audit_action=' This employee record has been  deleted ';   

    insert into project_employee_audit(Emp_name,Emp_username,Emp_password,action,update_date) 
    values(@empname,@emp_username,@emp_password,@audit_action,getdate());

    PRINT 'AFTER DELETE Trigger fired.'
GO
```

This is my already created trigger script,Now when I try to execute it again ,it gives me error as" Must declare a scalar variable,can you tell me what's the problem in script.When it was Ok for first time now why it is giving me this error message ?

Comment: Show us the exact error you're getting.

Comment: Your trigger has a **fundamental flaw**: it looks like you're assuming it will always be called **once per row** - this is **NOT** the case in SQL Server - it will be called **once per statement** and the `Deleted` pseudo table can (and will!) contain **multiple rows**. So which one do you think will be selected by your statement `select @empname=d.Emp_Name from deleted d;` ?? IT will be an arbitrary row, and all others will be ignored.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should just be:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterDelete12] ON dbo.[project_employee] 
AFTER DELETE
AS

insert into project_employee_audit(Emp_name,Emp_username,Emp_password,action,update_date) 
select Emp_Name,Emp_username,Emp_Password,'This employee record has been  deleted ',getdate()
from deleted
```

Since [`deleted`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) is a pseudo-table and can contain multiple rows (or no rows). There's no guarantee even that your separate assignments to scalar variables will get values consistently from the same (arbitrary) row